Performance Issues with .NET 6 LTS Apps on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Compared to 20.04 LTS
We’re experiencing significant performance degradation with our .NET 6 LTS applications after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 24.04. Despite performing various performance tune-ups and ensuring that the hardware and resource allocations are identical, we've observed no improvements. We suspect that this slowdown might be related to changes in the new kernel.
To analyze the issue, we developed a simple tool using .NET that performs tasks like signing data with a self-signed certificate (SHA-256), reading app configuration files, chain builds, and converting private keys to objects. Across the board, these operations are noticeably slower on Ubuntu 24.04 compared to 20.04.
Our applications performed well on Ubuntu 20.04S, but with its EOL approaching, we're compelled to migrate to 24.04, however the performance hit has been a major roadblock for us and we are unable to proceed with the migration due to this issue.
Has anyone else encountered similar issues, or can anyone provide insight on what might be causing this slowdown in Ubuntu 24.04?
The below screenshot describes the slowness with the time.


We used same performance vms to demonstrate this issue.
We performed some tune-ups like enabling swap/ disabling swap.
Disabled Apparmor
Downgraded Openssl to the same version of Ubuntu 20.04 has, etc.
Using same Signed Certificates that we used in Ubuntu 20.04

